# Container Div non expanding to inner div content

Tags: css, html, height

I have been looking all night, and I have to be doing something incorrectly, as I have seen this question or similar has been posted before. My apologies for needing to ask it again.

I have a a container div that holds some other divs, that is not expanding with the inner div content. The code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/pR7bq/

I can't remove height: 100%; from #container, because it needs to accomodate less content as well. I have seen the mention of using

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

but I'm either using it incorrectly or it's not working. I found this well written out answer to the same or similar problem here: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best), however, I'm at a loss as to where to put the code. My best attempts have yielded failure. I have also tried using overflow attributes, but I don't want the scrollbar to appear on the div rather than the page, if that makes sense.

I appreciate all help, and thank you in advance.

Comment: When I use
    height:auto;
it fits to the content, but when there is very little content, it doesn't extend to bottom of the viewing window. 

@Rohit Azad, min-height works BRILLIANTLY! Thank you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now used to `min-height` not **height**

**as like this**

```
#container{
height:100%; // remove this line
min-height:100%; // add this line 
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pR7bq/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your container styling:

```
#container{
    width:80%;
    background:#f6f6f6;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

By using height auto, the browser tries to determine a height for the element that will cover all of its children.

When you used height: 100%, it determined the height based upon the element container's parent height.

Answer (score 0):

i usually just throw a class like this in my css

```
.iefix{ clear: both;font-size: 1px;}
```

then i throw it in a div under the divs that aren't behaving in IE

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
    <div class="iefix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use height auto or dont define height to solve your problem